# Creating a map between N images and N labels using CNN

Tags: machine-learning, cnn, image-classification, theory

I have seen classification CNNs that train with numerous images for a subset of labels (i.e. Number of images >> Number of labels), however, is it still possible to use CNNs when the number of images = Number of labels?

specifically consider: having N settings that you can control to generate a unique image. Is it possible to make a CNN that can describe the mapping? (Is CNN the right architecture to use?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have single training data for each image (Number of image = Number of labels), no architecture is a good architecture. All good image models are deep learning model and are data hungry. If you have just a single image for each level it will not be able to learn anything

Comment: Is it fair to say then that one should approach it as a regression problem, and in this case maybe we can get okay results with a minimal data set as  I mentioned above? The point you make is fair and is noted, but in the case where you cannot generate a lot of data are there any tricks to be played that can help us?